# Guessing the appropriate 'distribution' of an observation to perform some form of sensitivity analysis

Tags: distributions, estimation, simulation

I wish to run some simulations on the 'estimates' of an event provided by experts (or historical data if available).

For example: The technology manager of company X says that probably 300-1000 computers in the organization (out of say 100,000 in total) have Windows XP that needs to be phased out.

Now this is an estimate, he's not sure of the number. Let's take 2 scenarios:

1. It's worth spending time/money to sample and estimate (i.e., value of information is worth the effort)
2. It's not worth the effort to perform any form of sampling and let's go with the estimate.

In either case, I wish to 'simulate' this model (with other similar) variables. You may think of it is wanting to run Monte-Carlo Simulations, but I don't want to put a specific solution to the idea, for the sake of discussion.

The question is then this - given sampling is done, can you 'guess' the appropriate probability distribution (I think this is doable, if I remember correctly from statistics, not sure though). And if sampling is NOT performed, how best to guess it?

Note: If my question is 'fuzzy' I'll surely revise it as I receive some comments/answers to make it more clear. The example above may not be the best one but nevertheless let's go with it for the sake of example. If a better example is suggested, I'll surely add it to the question

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how a simulation will provide any additional information or insight in this situation.  It will merely reflect the assumptions that go into it.  At worst, it will obscure those assumptions and make it seem you know more than you really do.

Comment: @whuber: So in which situations would you want to perform a simulation like this?

Comment: I wouldn't ever do a simulation like this.  Simulations are wonderful and can provide great insight, but there's so little information in this situation in the first place, and it's so uncertain, it's hard to see what simulation could do for us.

Comment: @whuber :I agree the example is a bit contrived - my intent is to gauge potential impacts for certain variables in a feasibility study and I wish to be able to simulate it to see how much it would vary and get some more insight. Could you suggest a better example? I'll add it to the question to make it more clear!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking me to make up a question for you :-).  I can't do that because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what I am looking for can be found in the work done by [David B. Hertz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_B._Hertz). The link to the pdf: http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/pdfiles/papers/probabilistic.pdf - specifically the data at the end of the file is THE thing I was looking for - a reverse mapping based on whatever understanding one has of the data. I tried adding the screen shot but seems I only get an option for linking to a URL but not uploading an image :(

But if you go the 'end' - the very last page of the pdf, it lists down a 'decision model' to help choose distribution models for the observation(s). Of course, it's just a guideline and simulations must be approached with care, since they can obscure a large number of assumption (or even mislead the results). But I just wanted something informational in this regard.